# Clicking a checkbox with protractor?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, protractor

**HTML code**

```
<div class="check-box-panel">
<!--
 ngRepeat: employee in employees 
-->
<div class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="employee in employees">
    <div class="action-checkbox ng-binding">
        <input id="John" type="checkbox" ng-click="toggleSelection(employee.name)" 
                   ng-checked="selection.indexOf(employee.name) > -1" value="John"></input>

    <label for="John">
        ::before
    </label>
<!--
 John               
 end ngRepeat: employee in employees 
-->

<div class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="employee in employees">
<div class="action-checkbox ng-binding">
    <input id="Jessie" type="checkbox" ng-click="toggleSelection(employee.name)" 
               ng-checked="selection.indexOf(employee.name) > -1" value="Jessie"></input>

    <label for="Jessie"></label>
```

**I tried using jQuery**

```
element(by.repeater('employee in employees')).element(by.id('Jessie')).click();
```

**also,I tried using css**

```
element(by.repeater('employee in employees')).$('[value="Jessie"]').click();
```

But it didn't do the job. Any other way I can click on the particular Checkbox?

Answer (score 9):

Alright I had a very similar issue where I couldn't click the checkbox. It turned out I had to click the checkbox label. However if you want to do any checks on if the checkbox is selected then you have to check the actual checkbox. I ended up making two variables, one for the label and one for the actual checkbox.

```
JessieChkbxLabel = element(by.css("label[for='Jessie']"));
JohnChkbxLabel   = element(by.css("label[for='John']"));

//Click the Jessie checkbox
JessieChkbxLabel.click();

//Click the John checkbox
JohnChkbxLabel.click();
```

Answer (score 3):

You should just need to use element(by.id('Jessie')) to grab your object. The issue you might be having is that click() returns a promise, so you need to handle that with a .then. So something along the lines of:

```
element(by.id('Jessie')).click().then(function(value) {
   // fulfillment
   }, function(reason) {
   // rejection
});
```

Comment: But how will it be identified as a checkbox element?It could very well click on the corresponding text?Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: My understanding is that it's not actually 'clicking' on the page, it sends a 'you have been clicked' message to the element which then calls: toggleSelection(employee.name).

Comment: A couple extra points from the API: element(locator) returns an ElementFinder, it can be treated as a WebElement for most purposes, in particular, you may perform actions (i.e. click), and an ElementFinder does not actually attempt to find the element until an action is called. https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementFinder

Answer (score 1):

Aside from checking the `id` directly, you can also [`filter`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.filter) the desired element checking the employee name:

```
var employee = element.all(by.repeater('employee in employees')).filter(function (elm) {
    return elm.evaluate("employee.name").then(function (name) {
        return name === "Jessie";
    });
}).first();
employee.element(by.css("input[type=checkbox]")).click();
```